# How to display bootstrap cards in pinterest like masonry style?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, grid, nuxt.js, masonry

I have created layout in bootstrap 4.6 grid layout but in between cards row space are there. so, I want to make grid layout cards like pinterest style layout.i used masonry-layout package in nuxt js. Code given below.

```
<template>
<div class="row mt-2 masonry-grid">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="card">
            <h5 class="card-header">
                Company Information
            </h5>
            <div class="card-body">
                <dl class="row mt-2" v-if="profileResult">
                    <dt class="col-sm-5">Name:</dt>
                    <dd class="col-sm-7">{{ profileResult.name }}</dd>

                    <dt class="col-sm-5">Ticker:</dt>
                    <dd class="col-sm-7">{{ profileResult.symbol }}</dd>

                    <dt class="col-sm-5">Exchange:</dt>
                    <dd class="col-sm-7">{{ profileResult.exchange }}</dd>

                    <dt class="col-sm-5">Industry:</dt>
                    <dd class="col-sm-7">{{ profileResult.industry }}</dd>

                    <dt class="col-sm-5">Sector:</dt>
                    <dd class="col-sm-7">{{ profileResult.sector }}</dd>

                    <dt class="col-sm-5">Website:</dt>
                    <dd class="col-sm-7">{{ profileResult.website }}</dd>
                </dl>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="card">
            <h5 class="card-header">
                Stock Chart {{ this.price ? '(' + this.price + ')' : '' }}
            </h5>
            <div class="card-body p-0">
                <div id="container" ref="container" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h3 class="card-title">About Company</h3>
            </div>
            
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="mb-1 text-center">
                            <img :src="logoResult.url" alt='logo' v-if="logoResult && logoResult.url">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <p v-if="profileResult && profileResult.description">
                            {{ profileResult.description.substring(0, 650).concat('...') }}
                        </p>
                        <p v-else>
                            it is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="card">
            <h5 class="card-header">
                Dividends
            </h5>
            <div class="card-body p-0">
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item">An item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">A second item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">A third item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">A fourth item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">And a fifth one</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h3 class="card-title">Snowflake Analysis</h3>
            </div>
            
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>
                    Apple Inc. designs, manufactures, and markets smartphones, personal computers, tablets, wearables, and accessories worldwide.
                </p>
                <p>Rewards</p>
                <p>Earnings are forecast to grow 4.13% per year</p>
                <p>Earnings grew by 11.2% over the past year</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="card">
            <h5 class="card-header">
                Financial Health
            </h5>
            <div class="card-body p-0">
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item">An item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">A second item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">A third item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">A fourth item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">And a fifth one</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="card">
            <h5 class="card-header">
                Actionarsstrukture
            </h5>
            <div class="card-body">
                <template v-for="oneNews in news">
                    <a :href="oneNews.url" target="_blank" :key="oneNews.uuid">
                        <h6>
                            {{ oneNews.title }}
                        </h6>
                    </a>
                    <p :key="oneNews.uuid+'description'">
                        {{ oneNews.description }}
                    </p>
                </template>
                <template v-if="!news.length">
                    <h3>No news found.</h3>
                </template>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
            <h5 class="card-header">
                Future Growth
            </h5>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>
                    Analyst Future Growth Forecasts
                </p>
                <p>Rewards</p>
                <p>Earnings are forecast to grow 4.13% per year</p>
                <p>Earnings grew by 11.2% over the past year</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import darkTheme from '../../plugins/dark'
import defaultTheme from "../../plugins/default";

export default {
    watch: {
        "$route": {
            handler: async function (to, from) {
                console.log('route watch', to, from);
                let { default: Masonry } = await import('masonry-layout');
                let grid = new Masonry('.masonry-grid', { 
                    percentPosition: true,
                    initLayout: false,
                });
            }, 
            deep: true,
            immediate: true
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        if (process.client) {
            this.loadMasonryLayout();
        }
    },
    methods: {
        async loadMasonryLayout() {
            let { default: Masonry } = await import('masonry-layout');
            let grid = new Masonry('.masonry-grid', { 
                percentPosition: true,
                initLayout: false,
            });
        }
    }
};
```

can you please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would use jQuery plugin https://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: @ITgoldman okay. then how it is working in nuxt js? can you please elaborate.

Comment: Give a try to vanilla CSS grid masonry: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/native-css-masonry-layout-css-grid/ No need for JS here.

Comment: Bootstrap 4.6 requires jQuery so just add the plugin.js file. Then read the docs, probably place some divs in a container and run $(".container").masonry();

Comment: @ITgoldman can you please explain with example code in nuxt js.

Comment: Since Nuxt JS is based on Vue which uses virtual dom, using jQuery wouldn't be natural. Instead maybe you should look at examples from https://vuejsexamples.com/tag/masonry/

Comment: @kissu can you please explain how to use that?

Comment: @ITgoldman import jQuery + Bootstrap for something already working with vanilla CSS? Hm...no.

Comment: @JinalSomaiya did you read the article? This is some CSS. Apply that to your template, nothing exotic here.

Comment: @kissu i read the doc and implement it but not working as expected.

Comment: Can you please be more specific here?

Comment: @kissu i go through your given link article and follow that. but not working as expected.

Comment: Can you please be more specific here as of what is not working?

Comment: @kissu it is not working means that i have tried using css given in link. with above template code with bootstrap classes.

Comment: Alright, good luck with your issue. As a last resort, you can check or my answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A8816585+masonry